# Normalizing and denormalizing rows in a dataframe

Tags: dataframe, machine-learning, deep-learning

I have a dataframe with 20k rows and 100 columns. I am trying to normalize my data across rows. Scikit's MinMaxScaler doesn't allow me to do this by rows. It has something called minmax_scale that allows row normalization but I cannot denormalize it later. At least, I don't see how to do it. How would you guys do it?

Comment: `normaliser.fit_transform(df.T)`

Comment: clever solution @Chris. I love it.

Answer (score 1):

From [`sklearn.preprocessing.minmax_scale`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.minmax_scale.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 5],
                   'B': [88, 300, 200]})

# Find and store min and max vectors
min_values = df.min()
max_values = df.max()

normalized_df = (df - min_values) / (df.max() - min_values)

denormalized_df= normalized_df * (max_values - min_values) + min_values

 A    B
 1   88
 2  300
 5  200
    A         B
 0.00  0.000000
 0.25  1.000000
 1.00  0.528302
   A      B
 1.0   88.0
 2.0  300.0
 5.0  200.0
```

Comment: Thank so much. This is great and easy to follow. Only problem with this approach is if I have zero values in the dataframe, I will get NaN but that's easy to replace.